# How to insert social icons using Angular Material like the Angular.io/resources site?

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

I've installed Angular Material and have been able to use the icons by simply importing the material module and using the mat-icon element:

```
<mat-icon>mood</mat-icon>
```

However I would like to use the social icons like the one on the [angular.io/resources](https://angular.io/resources) site.

When I inspect the element it seems they are drawing an svg using the path element's d attribute value, however I'm not sure how the Angular community usually gets these data values, is there a standard resource developers use rather than the tedious task of drawing it out themselves? At the moment I just resort to copying and pasting the d value lol, however I'm wondering if there's a more practical approach developers use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a svg file (inkscape, illustrator) or download it and register it like this in a service:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MaterialIconsService {
    constructor(private iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
                private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('my-icon', this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/path/my-icon.svg');
    }
}
```

Then you can use in it in your html

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="my-icon"></mat-icon>
```

More information here:  https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIconRegistry

Comment: Hi I know about this, but I'm wondering if there is a free source repo of SVG data plots like the one shown above for icons which the community tends to use - instead of creating a svg file to being with for something so common as social icons such as twitter, github, etc.

Comment: I like to use either material icons or fontawesome icons. Otherwise you can also search for svg icons on google ?

Answer (score 0):

All the Material icons are open source.

1. Go to the Material Icons site.
2. Click on an icon.
3. Click on the SVG download link at the bottom left of the page.

Alternatively click on the link to "git repository". Where you can browse the source repo and download some or all of the icons.